# Преобразование txt файла в типизированный

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Задача состоит в том, чтобы сначала преобразовать txt файл в типизированный и затем уже из типизированного файла заполнять record.

Но у меня не получается преобразовать мой файл in_file.txt в типизированный

Как выполнить преобразование txt файла в типизированный файл?

Пример файла:

```
название 1233424
название2   4543
...
```

```
Const
     N = 10;
Type
things = record
name: string[12];
price: longint;
end;

Var
input_file: text;
type_file: file of things;
arr: array[1..N] of things;

begin
 assign(input_file, 'in_file.txt');
 reset(input_file);
end.
```

Comment: Пример файла, конечно, нужно самим придумать для ответа на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Мне даже ссылка на документацию сойдет, чего-то не найти просто, как это делать

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, появился пример.

Comment: @SOFL, что-то у меня ощущение, что никак. только считать его в массив record'ов, а потом сериализовать.

Comment: Осталось понять что такое типизированный файл...

Comment: 1. Открыть текстовый файл. 2. Считать из него всё в arr. 3. Создать type_file. 3. Циклом записать содержимое arr в type_file. 4. Не забыть закрыть оба файла. 5. Profit.

Comment: @kami, так я так и делаю, но ошибка invalid file type

Comment: @kami, assign(type_file, 'type_fll');
     rewrite(type_file); writeln(type_file, arr[i].name, arr[i].price);